# Implementing the gridview paging with database

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, paging

I am binding dataset to a gridview,Which has 1000 records in it.As you know sending this entire  dataset across a wire is costly.
In the gridview i use paging which is set to 20 records per page.
Since sending entire dataset is costly ,so i  want to send 20 records at a time.
How can i implement this?
Is there any changes i need to do in the stored procedure?
Anybody suggest me the pros and cons of this approach?
Any pointers and resources are most welcome.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to a post I answered couple days ago:
[What is the best procedure to implement paging in a gridview considering size of Record ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787949/what-is-the-best-procedure-to-implement-paging-in-a-gridview-considering-size-of)

Answer (score 2):

Custom paging. [here explnation about some methods](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingLarge.aspx)
Hard implement and to maintain. Please write a bit more about data and what you do with it after it gets back from server, so we can help you with better suited option.