# Is it possible to speed up databinding of an ASP.NET GridView by using Parallel.Invoke?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, parallel-processing

I have an asp.net GridView that takes a long time to load due to a lot of columns and (potentially based on user input) a whole lot of rows. I am already using AJAX, but was wondering if calling the DataBind method from within Parallel.Invoke could increase performance without running the risk of corrupting the data. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Personal opinion:** This doesn't seem really useful. Most of the time, your bottleneck is the data transfer from the database to the server. The cost of databinding is negligible in comparison. **Objective opinion:** do a lot of profiling. Don't go randomly changing code without facts.

Comment: I have. The query runs fast, it is the binding of each cell that takes a while to load the grid.

Comment: Have you considered using a repeater instead of a gridview?

Comment: I think you should fetch only those rows from database which is required to show on the grid. here is a good link by which you can go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787949/what-is-the-best-procedure-to-implement-paging-in-a-gridview-considering-size-of