# C# Type as a Parameter in Object Creation in Efficient Way Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I am creating an event system for a game, I have the Abstract Class Event, and different subclasses, so far, I have made specific Methods for the creation of Each, but I would like to create them directly of their specified type

```
public void CreateEvent (Type t)
{
    GameObject NewEvent = new GameObject();
    NewEvent.AddComponent<t>();
}
```

This code gives an error message:

> t is a variable but is used as a Type

Comment: See generics [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606595/understanding-c-sharp-generics-much-better/3606655), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632/what-is-cool-about-generics-why-use-them) you can make your function like this `public void CreateEvent<T> ()` and call `NewEvent.AddComponent<T>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm making this more simple than it should be, but I think this is what you want:

```
public void CreateEvent<T>()
{
    GameObject NewEvent = new GameObject();
    NewEvent.AddComponent<T>();
}
```

But also, in keeping with standard case and naming conventions, `NewEvent` should really be `newEvent`:

```
public void CreateEvent<T>()
{
    GameObject newEvent = new GameObject();
    newEvent.AddComponent<T>();
}
```

Comment: And if you really want to pass in the type bcz you cannot do generics for some reson there's an overload [`AddComponent(typeof(T))`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html).

Comment: The first option didn't work, it says :The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'GameObject.AddComponent<T>()'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'UnityEngine.Component'. The second option works quite well and I will just use that one Thanks

Comment: @PabloLongobardi, I'm glad you got it working! The sample I gave *should* work, but it would also depend on how you are using `T` inside of `AddComponent()`.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston `AddComponent()` is [specified by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) (look at the generic version, the string parameter version is deprecated).

Comment: @Draco18s, ah, thanks! I confess I am not familiar with Unity

Comment: That error mean yo're trying to attach something to game object that isnt' a component? Is your type derived from MB? You cannot attach anything to a gameobject. It can have unexpected issues.

Comment: @user14492 yes, this class was derived from MB, the issue was more related to Type as a Parameter, but the solution worked just fine