# C# Generic class vs Generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

What's the advantage of making a class generic as oppose to just make the method generic? Under which circumstance would you want to use a generic class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632/what-is-cool-about-generics-why-use-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some of my list:

- With generic class, you can have generic properties as well. Which you can use together with generic methods you have on your generic class.
- For code reusability. You don't want to call again the same generic
  method on different non-generic class, although you can do that, but
  not a good practice though. You want to put all your related generic
  methods under generic class.
- With generic class, what you pass on the type of entity in class, can be used by all generic methods and generic properties.
  With only generic method, you cannot **re-use** that, unlike with a
  generic class.